# Matrix equation $P^TAP=A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Let $A\in \mathcal{M}_{m\times m}(\mathbb R)$ , $det(A)=1$ , $A$ is positively definite. Which matrices $P$ satisfy the equation
$$P^TAP=A$$
In fact I am interested in sequences of traces $tr P^n$ of the iterations of such solutions.

In dimension $2$ one can show that
$$P^n=\left(
        \begin{array}{cc}
          \cos n\phi& -\beta \sin n\phi \\
         \alpha \sin n\phi  & \cos n\phi\\
             \end{array}\right)$$
for some $\phi, \alpha, \beta$ satisfying$\alpha\beta=1$
hence $tr P^n= 2\cos n\phi$.

Comment: Two comments: All invertible $P$ with this property is a group. The second comment:the expresion $P^TAP$ instead of $P^{-1}AP$ remind me of the following: after change of coordinate with linear part $P$ the first fundamental form of the surface would be replaced by $P^T\mathcal{F}P$ instead of $P^{-1}\mathcal{F}P$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As $A=L^\top L$, for some $L\in M_{m\times m}(\mathbb{R})$, $\det L=1$, you can rewrite $P^\top L^\top LP=L^\top L$ and then multiply both sides by $L^{-1}$, etc., obtaining $(L^{\top})^{-1}P^\top L^\top LPL^{-1}=(LPL^{-1})^\top LPL^{-1}=I$, i.e. each $LPL^{-1}$ must be orthogonal.

As traces are preserved under conjugation, you can assume $L=I$, and so your question is reduced to studying traces of orthogonal matrices. The trace is the sum of eigenvalues, which are all modulus 1 complex numbers for orthogonal matrices.

Comment: It would be interesting to compare the two lie groups: centralizer of A and the other one mentioned in the question.

Comment: Centraliser of $A$, i.e. $\{X \in GL_m\mid AX=XA\}$ is a different beast - it depends on eigenvalues of $A$. It's quite small if they are all different, and the whole $GL_m$ is they are all the same.

Comment: Yes I see. On the other hand the Lie algebra of the other group is $V^T A+AV=0$

Answer (score 2):

Using the vec operator, any matrix $X$ such that $vec A$ is an eigenvector of $(X\otimes X)^T$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $1$ would work.